# Jmeter Response assertion failure on image URL matching with DB

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Response assertion failure for below assertion with DB? how to fix it?

**XML value**

[image]

**DB table**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tick `JMeter Variable` radiobutton in order to make this work as you expect

[image: JMeter Response Assertion]

Your current setup is comparing `${imageurl_1}` with the parent sampler response.

See documentation on [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more details.

Also be aware that you can check JMeter Variables names and values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri T for reminding me to tick JMeter Variable and see my another requirment in below question.

Answer (score 0):

For below details how is it possible to set values for Response assertion? only image URL path saved in DB and need to match with full image URL in XML?

[image]

Test failed for these configuration

Assertion failure message: Test failed: variable IMAGEURL expected to equal /

****** received  : [[[http://tcc.cad/abc/klj.jpg]]]/abc/klj.jpg

****** comparison: [[[                                               ]]]/abc/klj.jpg

[image: Test failed for these configuration]